# In Swift, how do you convert a String to Int64?

Tags: swift, string, long-integer, int64

I am loading in lines from a text file with very large numbers. `String` has the `toInt` method, but how do you convert a string to an `Int64` which will be able to handle the large numbers?

I don't see a `toInt64` method or a `toLong` etc. There must be a way, but I haven't found anything by searching yet.

Alternatively I guess I could read the numbers in the string digit by digit (or by groups of digits) and then add them together with appropriate factors of ten, but that seems like overkill. Or maybe the proper way is to read the data in a binary form and convert it that way?

Thanks

Comment: If you compile as a 64-bit app then `Int` *is* a 64-bit integer.

Comment: While the answers below are perfectly valid, in my case @MartinR 's answer was the most helpful. If you add it as an answer I can give you the answer credit.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

As of Swift 2.1.1 you can simply initialize `Int64` with `String`

```
let number: Int64? = Int64("42")
```

Comment: I don't think this words in Swift 4

Answer (score 10):

If you don't mind using `NSString`, you can do this:

```
let str = "\(LLONG_MAX)"
let strAsNSString = str as NSString
let value = strAsNSString.longLongValue
```

Note that unlike `toInt()`, `longLongValue` will return `0` if the string is not a legal number whereas `toInt()` will return `nil` in that case.

Comment: I'm trying to do this same thing but get an unsigned Int64. I tried looking through NSString but unfortunately theres no methods that return an UInt64. I was wondering if you had any ideas? Maybe it should be a new question?

Comment: @Lightbulb1 you can use the C function `strtoull`. Example: `strtoull(str, nil, 10)`. The first parameter is the string and the third parameter is the base to convert from. I don't know what the second parameter dose.

Answer (score 4):

```
import Darwin

let strBase10 = "9223372036854775807"
let i64FromBase10 = strtoll(strBase10, nil, 10)

let strBase16 = "0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF"
let i64FromBase16 = strtoll(strBase16, nil, 16)
```

strtoll means STRingTOLongLong

http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=strtoll

Answer (score 1):

```
import Darwin
let str = ...
let i = strtoll(str, nil, 10)
```